# autoexpand window based on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, autosize

I have a window that contains datagridview, when the data added in datagrid, the datagridview will auto expand. Now I would like to auto expand the window if the datagridview expand due to loading of data.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: you mean u have window form that contains the datagridview and u want to expend that window form with datagridview?? well u have to bind the event but thats not that good practice, **let consider if u have 100 records it grid and each record occupying 20 pixel height, so ur form will take the height of 100*20 = 2000 pixels hopefully larger that ur screen height so u can not see the remaining records..** thats good the good practice but yes u have do it..